# Accessibility force enabling is not working in android jelly bean

Tags: android, talkback

My project need accessibility feature, I need to enable programmatically. I am using below code snippet to make on.

```
Settings.Secure.putString(context.getContentResolver(), 
                Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES, 
            appInfo);

        Settings.Secure.putString(context.getContentResolver(), 
                Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED, 
                "1");

        Settings.Secure.putString(context.getContentResolver(),
                                  Settings.Secure.TOUCH_EXPLORATION_ENABLED,
                                  "1");

Settings.Secure.putString(context.getContentResolver(),
                                        "touch_exploration_granted_accessibility_services",
                                  appInfo);
```

But it is not working does in a android device where 5.1 OS is available.
In lower versions it works as expected.
any changes in api after 4.0?

Comment: Are you developing an app or a service?

Comment: I am developing application.

Comment: You can't do this.  You should consider developing an accessibility service.  This gives you the proper access to these permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of the talk back app package name. In some of the devices we need to give the package name of the talk back apk . so this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Only apps that hold the `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission can modify `Settings.Secure` values. `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` is a `signature`-level permission, which ordinary Android SDK apps cannot hold.

You are welcome to create your own custom build of Android, turn that into a custom ROM, and install that ROM on Android devices. Your app, with `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`, can be a part of that ROM.

Comment: Yes i have all permissions , i mean to say our app has route permission . one more it works fine below ICS. 

But failing in device which has 5.1.

Comment: @ashokreddy: "Yes i have all permissions" -- again, you cannot hold `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`, unless your app is signed with the same signing key that signed the device firmware.

Comment: yes even signed build also not working and as i was telling it works fine upto ICS.

Comment: https://github.com/google/talkback/blob/master/src/instrumentation_tests/src/com/googlecode/eyesfree/testing/BaseAccessibilityInstrumentationTestCase.java
In above link they were taking some thing about jelly-bean.